# Django jquery with ajax. How to make jquery to listen id's of generated forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have created basic shopping basket where I can add products to my session. Ive added ajax in order to not reaload my website everytime i add something to my basket.
The thnging is that I have generated forms with my for loop. Each of the form has hidden input with the id of product and quantity I want to add. I have problem with finding a solution, how to make jquery listen to ID's of the forms (which has the ID's of products).I know I can do everyting by:

```
$(this).attr('id');
```

But when I try to press the button, everyting is just fine with the first one. But when I press the other one generated it doesnt do ajax, it is going the second section in my views.py where i check if request is not ajax.
And It happens with all buttons that are > first one.
I`m posting my codes bellow:

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//$('#custom_user_form').on('submit', function (event) {
//    event.preventDefault();
//    add_product();
//
//});

$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    add_product();
});

//$('button[type=submit]').on('click', function(){
//    var post_primary_key = $(this).attr('id').split('-')[2];
//    console.log(post_primary_key)
//    delete_message(post_primary_key);
//});


function add_product() {
    $.ajax({
        url: window.location.pathname+'add_product/',
        type: 'POST',
        datatype: 'json',
        async: false,
        data: {
            product_id: $('#product_id').val(),
            quantity: $('#quantity').val(),
            csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
        },


        success: function (json) {
            $('#quantity').val(0);
            $('#price span').remove();
            $("#price").prepend("<span><strong> <h3>Overall price of all your products in basket: </strong> " + json.price + "$$$</h3>Recently added products: " + json.name + "</span>");
            console.log("success");

        }

    });
};
```

});

my template with generating forms:

```
<tbody>
  {% if products %}
    {% for p in products %}
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{{ p.id }}</th>
      <td>{{p.name}}</td>
      <td>{{p.price}} $</td>
      <td>{{p.stock}} units</td>
        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <form id="custom_user_form" method="post" action="add_product/">
            <td>
                {% csrf_token %}

                {{ add_product_form.as_p }}

                <!-- Provide a button to click to submit the form. -->
                <input id="product_id" type="number" name="product_id" value={{p.id}} hidden="True" />
                <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" max="{{p.stock}}"  style="width: 100px"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="submit"  id = "{{p.id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
            </td>
        </form>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
  </tbody>
</table>
```

{% endif %}

and finally my views.py

```
def add_to_cart(request, category_id):

if request.is_ajax():
    if request.method == 'POST':

        product_id = request.POST.get('product_id')
        quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')

        price = 0.0
        if not request.session.get('koszyk').get(product_id, None):
            request.session['koszyk'][request.POST.get('product_id')] = 0

        item = ShopProduct.objects.get(id = product_id)
        quantity = float(quantity)
        item_price = float(item.price)
        price += quantity * item_price

        item.stock -= quantity
        item.save()

        request.session['koszyk'][request.POST.get('product_id')] += int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        request.session['koszyk']['cena'] += price

        new_item = ShopProduct.objects.get(id = product_id)
        name = new_item.name
        print "_"*100
        print name

        price = request.session['koszyk']['cena']

        status = 200
        data = {'status': 200, 'price': price, 'name': name}

        return HttpResponse(json.dumps(data), content_type="application/json")

elif not request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
    add_product_form = AddProductForm(data=request.POST, request_product_id=request.POST['product_id'])
    price = 0
    print "JEBLEM PIRNTA "*100
    if add_product_form.is_valid():
        if not request.session.get('koszyk').get(request.POST.get('product_id'), None):
            request.session['koszyk'][request.POST.get('product_id')] = 0

        item = ShopProduct.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('product_id'))
        quantity = float(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        item_price = float(item.price)
        price += quantity * item_price

        item.stock -= quantity
        item.save()

        request.session['koszyk'][request.POST.get('product_id')] += add_product_form.cleaned_data['quantity']
        request.session['koszyk']['cena'] += price
        products_list = ShopProduct.objects.all()

    else:
        print add_product_form.errors
        messages.error(request, 'Smth went wrong, check log')
else:
    add_product_form = AddProductForm()

koszyk = request.session['koszyk']
products_list = ShopProduct.objects.all()


return render(request, 'tango/cart.html', {'products_list': products_list}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

The question is how I listen to those ID's ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Repeated HTML ids are meaningless, therefore purge them from your multiple product forms all through, in favour of classes.

```
<form class="product_form" method="post" action="add_product/">
    <td>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ add_product_form.as_p }}
        <input type="hidden" class="product_id" name="product_id" value={{p.id}} />
        <input type="number" class="quantity" name="quantity" value="0" min="0" max="{{p.stock}}"  style="width: 100px"/>
    </td>
    <td>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
    </td>
</form>
```

Now attach your `add_product` function as the submit handler for all the forms. In the handler, select everything by class, not id.

*Further explanation in comments*

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.product_form').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        //remember the form element
        var $form = $(this);

        //disable the submit button and remember it for later 
        var $button = $form.find("button[type='submit']").attr('disabled', true);

        //find the product_id, quantity and price fields in the form
        var $price = $form.find(".price");
        var $product_id = $form.find(".product_id");
        var $quantity = $form.find(".quantity");

        //Now do the ajax
        $.ajax({
            url: window.location.pathname + 'add_product/',
            type: 'POST',
            datatype: 'json',
            // async: false,//NO, never use async: false!!!
            data: {
                product_id: $product_id.val(),
                quantity: $quantity.val(),
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()
            }
        }).then(function(json) {
            $price.find("span").remove();
            $quantity.val(0);
            $price.prepend("<span><strong> <h3>Overall price of all your products in basket: </strong> " + json.price + "$$$</h3>Recently added products: " + json.name + "</span>");
        }, function() {
            //here give the user some indication that the ajax failed
        }).always(function() {
            $button.attr('disabled', false);
        });
    });
});
```

It's not strictly necessary here but you should get in the habit of using promise methods, `.then()`, `.done()`, `.fail()` and `.always()`, which are made availble by the object returned by `$.ajax`(). For morfe info, see [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! But in your jquery script you try to create a var named button by calling it with "this". "this" in this particular example is form not button. When I`m printing it out with console it returns me a form, same happens with $form. And everytime I try to make a reference to my variables it throws me "undefined"

Comment: I managed to get to the button with this function: var $button = $(this).parent().find('button');
But when I try to find the closest form to my button, and then if i search for quantity in that form, it throws me every quantity variable in my page, from all forms... Not only the one associated with my button

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I wasn't concentrating. I have edited the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple html elements with the same id (product_id,quantity). So when you get value using jquery you will have inconsistencies. try to get values using relative position of clicked button, so if you know wich button was clicked you can find product_id and quantity elements relative to your clicked button.

Also dont use submit button to ajax call, use input type="button" to prevent unnecessary postback.

Look: [Jquery Find Method](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [attribute Equal Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) to find elements by name instead of id

Comment: As you can see I`m using type=submit because in case where user doesn`t use JS in his browser it can still work as non-ajax view.

And I`m using unique id for button, and I managed to download its name, but how can I now make a reference to a quantity ?

Comment: if i understand you can use event.target to get the element that triggered the click event. then you can find the quantity value using jQuery find() method.
$triggerElement.closest('form').find("name['quantity']").val();